# Congruence mod application

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

**Question:** In the country of Zzyzzx the clocks have eight-hour faces. Suppose it is now five o’clock in Zzyzzx. What time will it be in 4725 hours?

**My answer:**
It is currently 5 hours. In 3 hours, the clock will return to zero (eight). After 4722 hours (3 hours subtracted above), the clock reads 2. The reason: 4722 ≡ 2 (mod 8)

**Another approach:**
(5 + 4725) mod 8 = 2

Is my answer correct? If yes, which one do you prefer? If no, can you suggest another way to do it? Thank you so much!

Comment: Right. The 2nd one is simpler. Mentally I found $4725\equiv 4720+5\equiv 5 \pmod 8, $ inferring that in $4725$ hours the clock will be $5$ hours forward from its present position.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet opps, so your answer is 5 hours forward while mine is 2 hours. Uhm? So complicated? What do you think?

Comment: Ah, sorry. 5 hours from its present position (which is also 5 hours) so it would also be 2 hours!

Comment: $Everyone$ makes mistakes like that :)